# Joining a NetApp to a domain on a Read Only Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, storage, kerberos, netapp, rodc

I have an isolated network, into which I've built a vfiler. The point of this network is that it's a non routed 'test' network.

However, there's a need for LDAP/Kerberos and CIFS access to the filer, via domain level accounts.

So we have Read Only domain controllers deployed.

To join a Windows box to the RODC, we would:

- create  a machine account by hand.
- join the domain, and specify the machine account password on the client.

A spot of googling finds me: https://kb.netapp.com/support/index?page=content&id=1012918

Where the advice is: Point the filer at a writable DC manually first.

I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it - I don't have writable DCs on this piece of the network deliberately. More importantly - my vfilers are on an ipspace, so I can't even temporarily 'jump over' to a network with the right access. (Which is sort of the point I guess, but even so...)

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can accomplish this - I'm assuming I may need to extract some information from my DC and transfer it over, such as a servicePrincipal. Or perhaps just 'set' my CIFS password manually somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with open the firewall temporarily. 
Alternative options might have been to configure a new virtual interface, add it to the IP space temporarily. That would have worked, but not in my environment (I was already using the VLAN/interface I would have needed to move) .

However, once you have access to a writable DC - the article above isn't quite correct.

You need to;

- set the prefdc with `cifs prefdc add <DC_IP>`
- set the ldap server, by `setting options.ldap.preferred` (typically, this will be the same as the DC).
- run the domain join and create the machine account.

Change the prefdc and preferred LDAP back to the original. Run `cifs resetdc` to force it.

Expect `No Trusted Logon Servers Available`  and `Client not found in Kerberos database` because your local RODCs won't have replicated the right details.

You may also need to adjust the computer account to be a member of a group so that it replicates fully. Part of the point of RODCs is that they don't have a complete database and omit some of the shared secrets as part of the machine account.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily jump back by adding a routable interface to the IPSpace- then you could join the domain and then remove that interface from the IPSpace.

Comment: Had considered it, but somewhat awkwardly -- I'm using that interface already. Unless there's a way to have two vlan tagged virtual interfaces with the same vlan in different ipspaces.

Comment: I think you can- if it's the same vlan, that means it's not on the same interface: if you did a `vlan create interface0 310` followed by another `vlan create interface0 310`, I think it would fail. If the second one was on another interface, though, that would be fine. And then you could assign interface1-310 to the nonprod IPSpace temporarily

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear - I've a single ifgrp that I'm vlan tagging on to different networks. I've got a 'core' network, where I've a vfiler, and a 'dirty' network where I've a vfiler. I'd have to move my new vfiler into 'core' in order to contact the DC, but I don't think I can do that without interrupting my existing core vfilers.

Comment: I'll ping you on the mailing list.